# Scraping images from websites in a list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to know if it is possible to scrape images in websites with a code that can work for all the types of websites (I mean independently of the HTML format). 
I have a list of websites ant I would need to get all the images related to each link. 
For instance:

`list_of links=`['https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5nxMx7d1K8S6nhjkPBFhHSM/withering-wit-and-words-of-wisdom-oscar-wildes-best-quotes' , 'https://www.lastampa.it/torino/2020/03/31/news/coronavirus-il-lockdown-ha-gia-salvato-almeno-400-vite-umane-1.38659569' , and so on]

In general, I would use:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link='...'

html = urlopen(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
for image in images: 
    print(image['src']+'\n')
```

but I have doubt in terms of html (can it be used for each website?) and about the image format (.jpg; would it be the same for all the websites?).

Thank you for all your comments and suggestions.

Comment: based on your code, do you only want to get jpg images?

Comment: no, actually. I would need to scrape all the images related to an article/news, regardless the format. For example, they could add jpg images, png.. and so on. Since I have a long list of websites, I would need to find a way to collect them without checking each page (it would be time consuming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the images are inside `src` tag and those image elements aren't dynamically added (not virtual DOM), modifying your code a little bit would work:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link= '...'

html = urlopen(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {})
for image in images: 
    print(image['src']+'\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Damzaky (and sorry for my late mark!)